# Blade - Recorrer dos arrays

Tags: html5, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, php7

Tengo una función que recoje los datos de un usuario y además recoge los rols que hay en el sistema , la idea es comparar los que hay en el sistema con los que el usuario tiene asignado  y checkearlos con un checkbox

El método que recoje los roles de un usuario es este

```
    public function editUser($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $rolesUser = $user->roles;
    $roles = Role::$roles;

    return view('users.edit', [
        'user' => $user,
        'rolesUser' => $rolesUser,
        'roles' => $roles
    ]);
}
```

Luego desde blade tengo este foreach que recorrer los roles y los muestra

```
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <ul>
                                <label for="roles">@lang('messages.Roles') *</label>
                                @foreach ($rolesUser as $role)
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="{{ $role->id }}"> {{ $role->display_name }}
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Ahora aquí me faltaría que no se como hacer , es que  que compare el array "roles" con "rolesUser" y deje chequeado los que coincide

Comment: Si puedes agrega que es lo que tiene Role::$roles para poder darte una mejor respuesta, pero de momento hasta donde he podido entender solo tienes que recorrer el arreglo roles que pasas a la vista y si los nombres coinciden le pones checked al input.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías ocupar acá es la funcion [`in_array`](https://www.bladephp.co/php-in_array)

Lo que daría lo siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<ul>
    <label for="roles">@lang('messages.Roles') *</label>
    @foreach ($rolesUser as $role)
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="{{ $role->id }}" @if(in_array($role->id, $roles)) checked="checked" @endif> {{ $role->display_name }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Aunque en este caso, todos los checkbox quedarían checkeados, ya que estas recorriendo los roles que el usuario tiene asignados asi que para que muestre todo el listado y solo marcar los del usuario debería quedar de esta manera:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<ul>
    <label for="roles">@lang('messages.Roles') *</label>
    @foreach ($roles as $role)
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="{{ $role->id }}" @if(in_array($role->id, $rolesUser)) checked="checked" @endif> {{ $role->display_name }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Espero te pueda ayudar.